# Can I say "Here are the celebrity SAT scores you are looking for, up to 80 rows of data."?

Tags: usage

I want to say that I have found 80 celebrities' SAT score information for my boss. Can I say this?

> Here are the celebrity SAT scores you are looking for, up to 80 rows
>   of data.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine.  In this case you can consider "celebrity SAT scores" to be a *compound noun* defining a particular thing.

I'm not certainly what you mean to imply by "up to 80 rows of data" though.  It seems either redundant or uncertain.  For example, suppose your boss was expecting more than 80, and you want to suggest that more are forthcoming, then say something like:

> Here are 80 **of the** celebrity SAT scores you asked for.  (I'll try and find more by tomorrow.)

Or suppose he asked for a specific 80 scores, and this is the result:

> Here are **the** 80 celebrity SAT scores you asked for.